# What is launch URL in a server app form Android game registered with Google Games Services

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-games

We have an Android game. We need to make a server-side app for it. I want to enable users to authenticate on server with a Google Play Games account. I found a doc on how to do that:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/offline-access
All is good but there is one thing I don't understand:

`Set the launch URL field with the url to access your server-side app`

What is a laucnh URL? Why do I need that? A player launches only the game itself and the games sends requests to server. A player shouldn't be visiting any URLs. What do I get wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That section is for associating it with a web based version of the app.  If there is no web version, don't do it.  If there is a web app, that's the URL to use.

Comment: So I just leave the field blank?

Comment: Yes.  There literally is no app to link it to.

Comment: Why do I bind the app to the game in the first place and not just register the app separately as a generic app that uses OAuth?

Comment: Because it allows you to make calls to Google Play Services from the web app.  If you don't need that, you wouldn't use this.  For things like shared leaderboards or the like.

Comment: When I tried the field was displayed red as required field. I can't leave it blank. Something is just wrong.